# Kubuntu upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, kubuntu, kde

I tried to update as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades/Kubuntu . But after updating all packages with muon-updater no upgrade available message pops up as described there. Check for updates is enabled in the systemsettings. Any ideas what could be wrong or how do I upgrade on the commandline?

I do not remember any errors when doing the muon update. And I get:

```
~> sudo do-release-upgrade
Auf neue Ubuntu-Freigabe prüfen
Keine neue Freigabe gefunden
```

(in german; means no update available)

But:

```
~> cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kubuntu-devel ( https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/kubuntu-devel ) has a thread "12.04 LTS Released" ( https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2012-April/006034.html ).

Alessandro Menti shares his experiences with the problem "No new release found": https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2012-April/006043.html

Answer (score 0):

From the command line you can do sudo do-release-upgrade and it will move you from Oneric to Precise.

Does Muon give you any error messages about when you try to do the update?

Comment: See extended question.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Did a "sudo apt-get autoremove -f" and after uninstalling a bunch of i386 packages received the GUI notification to upgrade the distro.