# kubuntu 11.10 muon not recognizing 12.04 exists!

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, kubuntu

I am in kubuntu...went to muon-update...performed updates system restarted now no updates available. System does not even recognize that 12.04 is out and available. No updates available for install as of 5/3/12. How to fix?

Comment: Earlier: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128016/kubuntu-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04

Answer (score 0):

I saw on here that the update manager isnt going to show 12.04 LTS upgrade until 12.04.1 comes out in about June or July. some say its no recommended to upgrade till 12.04.1 comes out. but you can press ALT + F2 then type `update-manager -d`. click "run". now update manager should have the upgrade to 12.04 LTS option now.

credit to:
[this unixmen.com tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-1004-1010-1104-to-ubuntu-1110-oneiric-ocelot-desktop-a-server/)

The above does not work in Kubuntu as update manager is not installed by default

Comment: you can also type it in the terminal.